# html helpers for dropdown lists?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Are there any helpers for displaying dropdownlists in asp.net-mvc?

I have an enumeration that I need to populate, and pre-select in a dropdownlist.

Answer (score 2):

The [FluentHtml](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=FluentHtml&referringTitle=Home) library from MVC Contrib has built-in support for generating select boxes from enumerations.

```
<%= this.Select("example")
        .Options<System.IO.FileOptions>()
        .Selected(System.IO.FileOptions.Asynchronous) %>
```

This outputs:

```
<select id="example" name="example">
    <option value="0">None</option>
    <option value="16384">Encrypted</option>
    <option value="67108864">DeleteOnClose</option>
    <option value="134217728">SequentialScan</option>
    <option value="268435456">RandomAccess</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="1073741824">Asynchronous</option>
    <option value="-2147483648">WriteThrough</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<%= Html.DropDownList() %>` has about 8 overloads that you can use.  You'll need to map your enumeration into an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` to pass to it though.  Something like this:

```
var names = Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyEnum));
List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach (var s in names)
{
   items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = s, 
                                    Value = s,
                                    Selected = (s == "SelectedValue") };
}
```

Comment: Personally, if I were doing it this way I'd use LINQ rather than creating a list and then populating it. Transforming a sequence of one thing into a sequence of something else is exactly what LINQ is good at. var items = Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyEnum)).Select(n => new SelectListItem() { Text=n, Value=n, Selected = (n == "SelectedValue") });